# PHP GD and transparent images sometimes work

Tags: php, gd

While reading up on the issues merging transparent images in PHP, it seems that everyone is in the "it works" or "it doesn't work" camps.  I have found a way to demonstrate each case.

I wish to take a PNG, cut an ALPHA hole in it and then merge it on top of another image.  In this case, I cut a hole in an image from google maps, and paste it over a red block. I have two images from google maps.  One is of Manhattan and one is of my house.   One works, and one does not.  The only difference is one was "saved" via a browser.

If you run the code below, you will see the difference in outputs.  Does anyone know why the same code would treat two PNG files completely differently?  It must be the difference in the PNG files themselves, but then what would it be?

```
<?php
sometimesworks("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728,-73.998672&zoom=12&size=400x400&maptype=hybrid", "google");
sometimesworks("https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/UQvV_dpBa3_rVf25pvLXKD3OwzF4FtPnHBHkzdWqjCQ5mlFqcFfId9echIgDMv_xYRRYzLaKEXphw7g=w2447-h1106", "myhouse");

function sometimesworks($p_image, $p_prefix)
{
$image_top =imagecreatefrompng($p_image);
$brush = imagecolorallocate($image_top, 0, 0, 0);  //create a black brush
imagefilledpolygon($image_top, explode(",", "10,10, 120,22, 80,280, 200, 191"), 4, $brush);  //fill a polygon
imagecolortransparent($image_top, $brush);  //turn the black to be transparent
imagepng($image_top, './'.$p_prefix.'.transparent.png');  //save the file to confirm that it is working.

//create a big red square
$image_bottom = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($image_top), imagesy($image_top));
$red = imagecolorallocate($image_bottom, 255, 0, 0);
imagefill($image_bottom, 0, 0, $red);
imagepng($image_bottom, './'.$p_prefix.'.red.png');

//merge the top onto the bottom.
$out = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($image_top), imagesy($image_top));
imagecopy($out, $image_bottom, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($image_top), imagesy($image_top));
imagecopy($out, $image_top, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($image_top), imagesy($image_top));
imagepng($out, './'.$p_prefix.'.out.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the above code is that the PNG files were of different type.  One was a truecolor image and the other was a palette.  The code to merge files differs depending on what is being done.

This is a good reference for the merging of "palette" based PNG files with transparency.